# Is it okay to call OracleConnection.Open() if the connection is already open?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, oracle, database-connection

IOW, is there a standard way of testing for this, a la:

```
if (! con.Open())
  con.Open();
```

?

UPDATE:
I guess I failed to mention that these are Oracle's ODP components I'm using. The OracleConnection component does not have a ConnectionState property.

Comment: System.Data.OracleClient.dll or Oracle.DataAccess.dll?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to separate your code into distinct layers to avoid this.  The connection should be opened only in the main method (in an API - not main method of application) - then passed to coordinating (private) methods that just consume the connection with no management of the connection (open, close, transaction operations, etc).  This keeps your code clean and your transactions / connections safe.

Comment: how this can be the answer?...is an excellent recomendation, but the subject of the question isn't responded

Comment: This question was changed even though the date stamps are not correct.  The original post had a lot more code that was not segregated.

Comment: I dont know how this relates to the actual question, but good advice.

Answer (score 15):

Use the [Connection.State](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oracleclient.oracleconnection.state.aspx) property to check whether the connection is already open

```
if(con.State == ConnectionState.Closed){
  con.Open();
}
```

Comment: NOTE: This does not work if the connection has been lost.  For example if you kill this session while the program is running, con.State will still be Open.  I would be interested to know if anyone has a low-overhead way to tell if the connection to the session is really open.  For example: what is the lowest cost interaction that you can do with the DB to check that the session is open?

Answer (score 4):

```
if(Con.State != ConnectionState.Open)
con.Open();
```

if you want open only closed connections you can use

```
if(Con.State == ConnectionState.Close)
con.Open();
```

ConnectionState: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.connectionstate.aspx

Comment: Shouldn't that second `if` be `==` not `!=`?

Comment: I guess I failed to mention that these are Oracle's ODP components I'm using. The OracleConnection component does not have a ConnectionState property.